# There is an issue that we are applying different value of Opacity on watermark logo but transparency is not changing

Tags: c#

There is an issue that we are applying different value of Opacity on watermark logo but transparency is not changing

library we are using for watermark is LazZiya.ImageResize we are using `ImageWatermarkOptions()` method

Solutions we tried

```
using (var img = Image.FromStream(stream))
{
    var imOps = new ImageWatermarkOptions 
    {
        Opacity = 35,
        Location = TargetSpot.Center
    };

    img.ScaleAndCrop(600, 300)
        .AddImageWatermark("wwwroot/images/icon.png", imOps)
        .SaveAs("wwwroot/upload/new-image.jpg");
}
```

- Tried converting images from jpeg to png as mentioned in their document

https://docs.ziyad.info/en/LazZiya.ImageResize/v4.1/image-watermark.md

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. So the only question is if those file paths to the images are correct? It looks like you just copied the example, including file paths. Can you show us the actual code you are using instead of copy and pasting the example?

Answer (score -1):

Opacity works from 0 to 1. please try with giving the value between 0 to 1 based on your requirement.

```
using (var img = Image.FromStream(stream))
{
var imOps = new ImageWatermarkOptions 
{
    Opacity = 1,
    Location = TargetSpot.Center
};

img.ScaleAndCrop(600, 300)
    .AddImageWatermark("wwwroot/images/icon.png", imOps)
    .SaveAs("wwwroot/upload/new-image.jpg");
}
```

Comment: According to their documentation ImageWatermarkOptions.Opacity is a value between 0 and 100.

Comment: Its mentioned in their library that opacity value resides between 0 to 100 in integer value https://prnt.sc/LDrD__sZyGyA  we are changing according to documentation

Comment: Can you provide us with your output.

Comment: Sorry I had not gone through their documentation. generally we've opacity from 0 to 1.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/agAkEFm_3LCq  This is our output with Opacity = 1,